# How do you get the coordinates from a drag event in the Google Maps API V3?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api, maps

I have made a Google Version 3 Geocoder , I want to be able to pick up the coordinates of the route when it is dragged. I know how to pick up the coordinates giving the start and end points, but, after change the route, I don't know how to do!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did this, and it works!

```
var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(rendererOptions);
...
google.maps.event.addListener(directionsDisplay, 'directions_changed',         
    function() {
                your code here
    }
);
```